# namespace query

Tags: c++

The below code give the compilation error

```
namespace X{
  int i;
}

void f(){

  int i;
  using X::i;  //compile error 'i’ is already declared in this scope

}
```

But if i replace this line with using namespace X, it compiles fine.
Can someone help understand differences.

Also in the modified code below, I was expecting the output for X::I to be 100 in all places, but it is not.

May be I have misunderstood the namespace concept ?

```
namespace X{
  int i;
}

void f(){
  int i=1;
  cout << "local I " << i << endl;  // prints 1 OK
  using namespace X;
  i=100;
  cout << "X::i " << i << endl;   // prints 100 OK. 
  cout << "X::i " << X::i << endl; // prints 10 why ?
}

main(){
  using namespace X;
  i=10;
  f();
  cout << "X::i " << i << endl; //prints 10 why ?
}
```

Thanks for any help to make me understand this.

Answer (score 2):

In `main()`:

```
using namespace X;
i = 10;
```

This sets `X::i` to 10.

> prints 10 why?

That's `^^` why.

Also, in `f()`: you have another local variable named `i` that **shadows** `X::i`, that's why `i` resolves to 1 and 100, respectively, and you can only access the other variable in the `X` namespace by explicitly specifying its namespace.

Comment: but wouldn't the statement i=100 in function f() set X::i to 100 ?

Comment: @irappa That is explained in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @irappa No, because the local variable shadows the global one, that's what I **just explained.**

Comment: ok so irrespective of whether using namespace X statement is present before local int i declation or after, the local i hides X::i ? I was under the impression that, since using namespace X is after local int i, the X::i hides the local i.  Thankyou. And why is the compile error with using X::i and not if i use using namespace X ?

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'using namespace X'...

if the variable 'i' is defined in X, then, for all references to the variable 'i', the compiler replaces it with 'X::i'. So in main(), when you say i=10, it's setting X::i to 10.

In f()...

you create a NEW variable called i. This is different from X::i. You set i to 1.  Then, you begin using namespace X. However, there is a naming conflict--when you say 'i', should it use the local 'i', or X::i? The C++ compiler handles this such case by identifying the variable 'i' with the LOCAL i. Because there is already an i defined in the function, it cannot introduce another i--the i in the namespace. So, in order to reference X::i, you have to explicitly say 'X::i'. Otherwise it thinks you're talking about the LOCAL i.

In the first example, when you say using X::i, you're not giving the compiler much of a choice. You're saying < I WANT TO CALL X::i 'i' >. However, it can't do this--because there's already an 'i' defined. Forcing the compiler to do this would result in two different variables having the same name--which cannot happen.

Hopefully this clarified things a bit. Comment with additional questions.

Comment: so you can think irappa about accepting his answer or upvote at least

Comment: @cf16 --are you talking to me or irappa?

Answer (score 0):

The `using X::i` Statement introduces a particular name into the scope. Apparently, the name `i` was already used so you will not be able to use it again.
Actually, namespaces are used to avoid possible name-clashing. With such short names, namespaces are actually overkill.